# How to setup Vue and webpack in my existing Express multi page project?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, ejs, vuetify.js

guys
I need a help regarding using Vue and webpack with my existing project.
I have built my website using nodejs express server among with ejs as templates.

actually, I want to change the front end of my website totally. And I wanna use Vuetify as the primary frontend framework. But I have never implemented web pack in an existing project. can anyone please help me to do it?

My project file structure is following:

```
├───includs
│       func.js
│       mailer.js
│       middlewares.js
│       
├───models
│       BruteForceSchema.js
│       coupon.js
│       invoice.js
│       payment.js
│       product.js
│       services.js
│       statement.js
│       ticket.js
│       user.js
│       
├───routs
│   │   auth.js
│   │   footer.js
│   │   index.js
│   │   products.js
│   │   profile.js
│   │   
│   ├───admin
│   │       coupon.js
│   │       index.js
│   │       plans.js
│   │       recharge.js
│   │       services.js
│   │       tickets.js
│   │       users.js
│   │       
│   └───clientarea
│           hostings.js
│           index.js
│           recharge.js
│           statement.js
│           tickets.js
│           
└───views
    │   404.ejs
    │   index.ejs
    │   
    ├───admin
    │   │   activeService.ejs
    │   │   editplan.ejs
    │   │   editservice.ejs
    │   │   index.ejs
    │   │   newplan.ejs
    │   │   plans.ejs
    │   │   recharge.ejs
    │   │   services.ejs
    │   │   users.ejs
    │   │   viewplan.ejs
    │   │   viewservice.ejs
    │   │   
    │   ├───coupon
    │   │       addnew.ejs
    │   │       edit.ejs
    │   │       index.ejs
    │   │       view.ejs
    │   │       
    │   ├───tickets
    │   │       index.ejs
    │   │       view.ejs
    │   │       
    │   └───users
    │           editUser.ejs
    │           userlist.ejs
    │           viewUser.ejs
    │           
    ├───auth
    │       login.ejs
    │       newpassword.ejs
    │       resetpwd.ejs
    │       signup.ejs
    │       
    ├───clientarea
    │   │   head.ejs
    │   │   hostings.ejs
    │   │   index.ejs
    │   │   recharge.ejs
    │   │   recharge_old.ejs
    │   │   statement.ejs
    │   │   viewhosting.ejs
    │   │   
    │   └───payments
    │           proceed.ejs
    │           
    ├───email
    │   │   resetdone.ejs
    │   │   welcome.ejs
    │   │   
    │   └───searvice
    │           renewDone.ejs
    │           renewFailed.ejs
    │           
    ├───footer
    │       aboutus.ejs
    │       contactus.ejs
    │       development.ejs
    │       privacy.ejs
    │       tos.ejs
    │       
    ├───inc
    │       admincpsider.ejs
    │       footer.ejs
    │       func.ejs
    │       header.ejs
    │       usercpsider.ejs
    │       
    ├───products
    │       buy.ejs
    │       filehosting.ejs
    │       index.ejs
    │       info.ejs
    │       shared-hosting.ejs
    │       wordpress.ejs
    │       
    ├───profile
    │       edit.ejs
    │       index.ejs
    │       
    └───tickets
            index.ejs
            newTicket.ejs
            view.ejs
```

Comment: I recommend playing around with the Vue CLI. It will give you an idea of how to set up everything including express, webpack, etc. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli

Comment: Forget About vue, I just wanna setup webpack with that project